# How to tell Perl to always run with use v5.010?

Tags: perl

When I write small programs or oneliners I cannot use `say`. I always need to put:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
```

In oneliners I can simply do `perl -E "say 'toto'"` but in regular programs I don't know how to do it...

Any idea?

Comment: `use feature 'say'` is the idiomatic way. Enabling a version brings with it a lot of things, not just `say`. Personally, I prefer using `-l` with one-liners, which adds newlines to `print`. It might not be a good idea to write code that relies on whoever running it is using a certain special setting.

Comment: Note that you can use `CORE::say` without `use 5.010;` or `-E`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the default `perl` command-line options using the `PERL5OPT` environment variable

```
PERL5OPT=-M5.010
```

or, more safely

```
PERL5OPT=-Mfeature=say
```

Answer (score 4):

This is verymuch by design. When `perl` is reading a program from a file, it remains in back-compatibility mode, so that older programs are not broken by features added in later versions. By saying

```
use 5.010;
```

you are saying you want at least 5.10, and thus it turns on all the features that were present in that version. This ensures that a file lacking such a declaration will not be confused.

Comment: Well, this is pretty the same a using vim in compatible mode. We are stuck in the 90s because of compatibility issues. I am sad :(

Comment: @nowox Don't be too sad.  Most Linux distros use Perl 4 style scripts under the hood.  Forcing your box to "upgrade" the interpretation of these scripts could be *unfortunate*.

Comment: @nowox: It's more akin to the fact that vim defaults to compatible mode if you don't tell it otherwise. The mere presence of a `.vimrc` file in your home tells it otherwise. It's a sensible way to not surprise old things, while making it easy for new things to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use an editor with a template or macro system to insert the boilerplate when you start a new file.  For example, Emacs has `skeleton.el` and `tempo.el` (plus numerous other packages you can install).

Comment: This is indeed the solution I am currently using (except I am a vim guy) :)